# Nodejs rest api delete function

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am writing nodejs rest API. I have problems with my delete function.
This my html code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in displayedCollection">
    <td>{{row.FirstNameAuthor}}</td>
    <td>{{row.LastNameAuthor}}</td>
    <td>
    <button type="button" ng-click="deleteWriter(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
    </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This my core.js code:

```
$scope.deleteWriter = function (row) {
    $http.delete('/writer', $scope.row)
          .error(function (data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
          });
    };
```

This my server.js code:

```
app.delete('/writer', function (req, res) {
    var reqBody = '';

    req.on("data", function (data) {
        reqBody += data;
        if (reqBody.length > 1e7) {//10MB
            httpMsgs.show404(req, res);
        }
    });
    req.on("end", function () {
        wr.delete(req, res, reqBody);
    });
})
```

Then I use function wr.delete to remove record from database.

```
exports.delete = function (req, resp, reqBody) { 

try {
    if (!reqBody) throw new Error("Input is nod valid");
    var data = JSON.parse(reqBody);
    if (data) {
        if (!data.idRegisterIssueContract) throw new Error("No such number");
        var sql = "DELETE FROM registerissuecontract ";
        sql += " WHERE idRegisterIssueContract =" + data.idRegisterIssueContract;
        db.executeSQL(sql, function (data, err) {
            if (err) {
                httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, err);
            }
            else {
                httpMsgs.send200(req, resp);
            }

        });
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Input is nod valid");
    }
}
catch (ex) {
    httpMsgs.show500(req, resp, ex);
}
};
```

But it does not work because reqBody is empty.

How can I fixed it?

Comment: What error? where is wr defined?

Comment: Are you trying to delete a record from a database? Have you considered using sequelize?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to delete a record from a database. But I think that I did something wrong in core.js.

Comment: One problem here is that the DELETE method should only use query parameters, not a body. I also question the need to send the whole row across. Usually deletes just take the ID of the object.

Comment: Your approach doesn't make sense. `DELETE /writer` means "Delete the resource at the URL /writer". There shouldn't be a request body.

Comment: How can I send my id from server.js to exports.delete?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an id in your delete route, like below :

**Client side :**

```
 $http.delete('/writer/' + id)
        .success(function(data) {
         console.log('Success: ' + data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
```

**Server side :**

```
   app.delete('/writer/:id', function (req, res) {

    var id = req.params.id;

    //DELETE YOUR RECORD WITH YOUR PARAM.

    return res.status(200);
}
```

Tell me if I've answered your question.

Comment: I have added this to my code but my id is hot defined in app.delete

Comment: I've updated my post, it should be work correctly now.